# Watchdog compatibility: A workaround for "CancelIoEx"

Tags: python, multithreading, winapi, asynchronous, python-watchdog

Using the python [watchdog](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/watchdog) file system events watching library I noticed that when being used under Windows Server 2003 it entered into "Polling Mode" thus stoping using asynchronous OS notification and, therefore, heavily reducing system performance under big amount of file changes.

I traced the problem to `watchdog/observers/winapi.py` file where `CancelIoEx` system call is used in order to stop `ReadDirectoryChangesW` call lock when the user wants to stop monitoring the watched directory or file:

(winapi.py)

```
CancelIoEx = ctypes.windll.kernel32.CancelIoEx
CancelIoEx.restype = ctypes.wintypes.BOOL
CancelIoEx.errcheck = _errcheck_bool
CancelIoEx.argtypes = (
    ctypes.wintypes.HANDLE,  # hObject
    ctypes.POINTER(OVERLAPPED)  # lpOverlapped
)

...
...
...

def close_directory_handle(handle):
    try:
        CancelIoEx(handle, None)  # force ReadDirectoryChangesW to return
    except WindowsError:
        return
```

The problem with `CancelIoEx` call is that it is not available until Windows Server 2008:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363792(v=vs.85).aspx

One possible alternative is to change `close_directory_handle` in order to make it create a mock file within the monitored directory, thus unlocking the thread waiting for `ReadDirectoryChangesW` to return.

However, I noticed that `CancelIo` system call is [in fact available](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363791(v=vs.85).aspx) in Windows Server 2003:

> Cancels all pending input and output (I/O) operations that are issued
>   by the calling thread for the specified file. The function does not
>   cancel I/O operations that other threads issue for a file handle. To
>   cancel I/O operations from another thread, use the CancelIoEx
>   function.

But calling `CancelIo` won't affect the waiting thread.

Do you have any idea on how to solve this problem? 
May be `threading.enumerate()` could be used issue a signal to be handled by each thread being `CancelIo` called from these handlers?

Comment: I'm the author of that line. I believe CancelIo is for canceling async IO operations only. It's as if ReadDirectoryChangesW was designed to be uninterpretable until CancelIoEx was later added. There is a "simple" solution though: implement the async (overlapped) version of ReadDirectoryChangesW. Then, if it works as I think it does, it should be possible to stop it by calling CancelIo in the same thread that calls ReadDirectoryChangesW. If you want to undertake this task, patch will be welcome.

Comment: @takoi Thank you very much for your comment. I think (I may be wrong) `read_directory_changes` could be implemented using the asynchronous mode of `ReadDirectoryChangesW` as described at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365465(v=vs.85).aspx retrieving its result through a completion routine. A lock for each thread could be acquired right after the asynchronous call has ben performed and released by the completion routine, one by one, or, at the same time, by `close_directory_handle`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The natural approach is to implement a completion routine and call to `ReadDirectoryChangesW` using its overlapped mode. The following example shows the way to do that:

```
RDCW_CALLBACK_F = ctypes.WINFUNCTYPE(None, ctypes.wintypes.DWORD, ctypes.wintypes.DWORD, ctypes.POINTER(OVERLAPPED))
```

First, create a WINFUNCTYPE factory which will be used to generate (callable from Windows API) C like functions from python methods. In this case, no return value and 3 parameters corresponding to

```
VOID CALLBACK FileIOCompletionRoutine(
  _In_     DWORD dwErrorCode,
  _In_     DWORD dwNumberOfBytesTransfered,
  _Inout_  LPOVERLAPPED lpOverlapped
);
```

[FileIOCompletionRoutine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364052(v=vs.85).aspx) header.

The callback reference as well as the overlapped structure need to be added to `ReadDirectoryChangesW` arguments list:

```
ReadDirectoryChangesW = ctypes.windll.kernel32.ReadDirectoryChangesW

ReadDirectoryChangesW.restype = ctypes.wintypes.BOOL
ReadDirectoryChangesW.errcheck = _errcheck_bool
ReadDirectoryChangesW.argtypes = (
    ctypes.wintypes.HANDLE,  # hDirectory
    LPVOID,  # lpBuffer
    ctypes.wintypes.DWORD,  # nBufferLength
    ctypes.wintypes.BOOL,  # bWatchSubtree
    ctypes.wintypes.DWORD,  # dwNotifyFilter
    ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.wintypes.DWORD),  # lpBytesReturned
    ctypes.POINTER(OVERLAPPED),  # lpOverlapped
    RDCW_CALLBACK_F  # FileIOCompletionRoutine # lpCompletionRoutine
)
```

From here, we are ready to perform the overlapped system call.
This is a simple call bacl just usefult to test that everything works fine:

```
def dir_change_callback(dwErrorCode,dwNumberOfBytesTransfered,p):
     print("dir_change_callback! PID:" + str(os.getpid()))
     print("CALLBACK THREAD: " + str(threading.currentThread()))
```

Prepare and perform the call:

```
event_buffer = ctypes.create_string_buffer(BUFFER_SIZE)
nbytes = ctypes.wintypes.DWORD()
overlapped_read_dir = OVERLAPPED()
call2pass = RDCW_CALLBACK_F(dir_change_callback)

hand = get_directory_handle(os.path.abspath("/test/"))

def docall():
    ReadDirectoryChangesW(hand, ctypes.byref(event_buffer),
                          len(event_buffer), False,
                          WATCHDOG_FILE_NOTIFY_FLAGS,
                          ctypes.byref(nbytes), 
                          ctypes.byref(overlapped_read_dir), call2pass)

print("Waiting!")
docall()
```

If you load and execute all this code into a [DreamPie](http://www.dreampie.org/) interactive shell you can check the system call is done and that the callback executes thus printing the thread and pid numbers after the first change done under `c:\test` directory. Besides, you will notice those are the same than the main thread and process: Despite the event is raised by a separated thread, the callback runs in the same process and thread as our main program thus providing an undesired behaviour:

```
lck = threading.Lock()

def dir_change_callback(dwErrorCode,dwNumberOfBytesTransfered,p):
     print("dir_change_callback! PID:" + str(os.getpid()))
     print("CALLBACK THREAD: " + str(threading.currentThread()))

...
...
...

lck.acquire()
print("Waiting!")
docall()
lck.acquire()
```

This program will lock the main thread and the callback will never execute.
I tried many synchronization tools, even Windows API semaphores always getting the same behaviour so, finally, I decided to implement the ansynchronous call using the synchronous configuration for `ReadDirectoryChangesW` within a separate process managed and synchronized using `multiprocessing` python library:

Calls to `get_directory_handle` won't return the handle number given by windows API but one managed by `winapi` library, for that I implemented a handle generator:

```
class FakeHandleFactory():
    _hl = threading.Lock()
    _next = 0
    @staticmethod
    def next():
        FakeHandleFactory._hl.acquire()
        ret = FakeHandleFactory._next
        FakeHandleFactory._next += 1
        FakeHandleFactory._hl.release()
        return ret
```

Each generated handle has to be globally associated with a file system path:

```
handle2file = {}
```

Each call to `read_directory_changes` will now generate `ReadDirectoryRequest` (derived from `multiprocessing.Process`) object:

```
class ReadDirectoryRequest(multiprocessing.Process):

    def _perform_and_wait4request(self, path, recursive, event_buffer, nbytes):
        hdl = CreateFileW(path, FILE_LIST_DIRECTORY, WATCHDOG_FILE_SHARE_FLAGS,
                       None, OPEN_EXISTING, WATCHDOG_FILE_FLAGS, None)
        #print("path: " + path)
        aux_buffer = ctypes.create_string_buffer(BUFFER_SIZE)
        aux_n = ctypes.wintypes.DWORD()
        #print("_perform_and_wait4request! PID:" + str(os.getpid()))
        #print("CALLBACK THREAD: " + str(threading.currentThread()) + "\n----------")
        try:
            ReadDirectoryChangesW(hdl, ctypes.byref(aux_buffer),
                              len(event_buffer), recursive,
                              WATCHDOG_FILE_NOTIFY_FLAGS,
                              ctypes.byref(aux_n), None, None)
        except WindowsError as e:
            print("!" + str(e))
            if e.winerror == ERROR_OPERATION_ABORTED:
                nbytes = 0
                event_buffer = []
            else:
                nbytes = 0
                event_buffer = []
        # Python 2/3 compat
        nbytes.value = aux_n.value
        for i in xrange(self.int_class(aux_n.value)):
            event_buffer[i] = aux_buffer[i]
        CloseHandle(hdl)
        try:
            self.lck.release()
        except:
            pass



    def __init__(self, handle, recursive):
        buffer = ctypes.create_string_buffer(BUFFER_SIZE)
        self.event_buffer = multiprocessing.Array(ctypes.c_char, buffer)
        self.nbytes = multiprocessing.Value(ctypes.wintypes.DWORD, 0)
        targetPath = handle2file.get(handle, None)
        super(ReadDirectoryRequest, self).__init__(target=self._perform_and_wait4request, args=(targetPath, recursive, self.event_buffer, self.nbytes))
        self.daemon = True
        self.lck = multiprocessing.Lock()
        self.result = None
        try:
            self.int_class = long
        except NameError:
            self.int_class = int
        if targetPath is None:
            self.result = ([], -1)

    def CancelIo(self):
        try:
            self.result = ([], 0)
            self.lck.release()
        except:
            pass

    def read_changes(self):
        #print("read_changes! PID:" + str(os.getpid()))
        #print("CALLBACK THREAD: " + str(threading.currentThread()) + "\n----------")
        if self.result is not None:
            raise Exception("ReadDirectoryRequest object can be used only once!")
        self.lck.acquire()
        self.start()
        self.lck.acquire()
        self.result = (self.event_buffer, self.int_class(self.nbytes.value))
        return self.result
```

This class specifies `Process` providing a process which perform the system call and waits until (or):

- A change event has been raised.
- The main thread cancels the request by calling to the `ReadDirectoryRequest` object `CancelIo` method.

Note that:

- get_directory_handle
- close_directory_handle
- read_directory_changes

Roles are now to manage requests. For that, thread locks and auxiliary data structures are needed:

```
rqIndexLck = threading.Lock() # Protects the access to `rqIndex`
rqIndex = {} # Maps handles to request objects sets.
```

**get_directory_handle**

```
def get_directory_handle(path):
    rqIndexLck.acquire()
    ret = FakeHandleFactory.next()
    handle2file[ret] = path
    rqIndexLck.release()
    return ret
```

**close_directory_handle**

```
def close_directory_handle(handle):
    rqIndexLck.acquire()
    rqset4handle = rqIndex.get(handle, None)
    if rqset4handle is not None:
        for rq in rqset4handle:
            rq.CancelIo()
        del rqIndex[handle]
    if handle in handle2file:
        del handle2file[handle]
    rqIndexLck.release()
```

And last but not least: **read_directory_changes**

```
def read_directory_changes(handle, recursive):
    rqIndexLck.acquire()
    rq = ReadDirectoryRequest(handle, recursive)
    set4handle = None
    if handle in rqIndex:
        set4handle = rqIndex[handle]
    else:
        set4handle = set()
        rqIndex[handle] = set4handle
    set4handle.add(rq)
    rqIndexLck.release()
    ret = rq.read_changes()
    rqIndexLck.acquire()
    if rq in set4handle:
        set4handle.remove(rq)
    rqIndexLck.release()
    return ret
```

Comment: Can you post the rest of your first callback mode implementation? I can't get your example to work at all. For one, FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED *must* be passed or else it won't be async, even if you pass overlapped and callback to ReadDirectoryChangesW.

Comment: Concerning FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED I changed a flags constant deffinition: WATCHDOG_FILE_FLAGS = FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS | FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED If you want my example set, I can send it to you instead posting so much code here.

Comment: So much work and the support for XP is still missing. Have you finished it? Has @takoi received it?